No sound from internal speaker
I just installed Ubuntu 24 on my laptop, but I can't get any sound from the speaker.  lspci | grep -i audio gives me this :
04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
04:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor (rev 01)
04:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller

have tried a lot of solutions that I found on forums, but nothing worked.
Thanks for your help.
